# AWS S3 sending download.txt file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up an S3 bucket behind CloudFront that is meant to serve static assets. My problem is doing a `/` on any directory with no file name will have the browser download a `download.txt` with 0 bytes. I have my S3 bucket setup for Static Website Hosting and is pubic, so I'm able to access my assets.

1. `https://s3-bucket.domain.com/path/to/file.jpg` -> get asset, working
2. `https://s3-bucket.domain.com/path/to/file-bad-name` -> Error status 403, working. Renders `error.html` from S3.
3. `https://s3-bucket.domain.com/path/to/` -> sends `download.txt`, not working

How do I configure #3 to not send a `download.txt` and render an error page instead?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that with #3 the status code is 200, which I was hoping I could set a Custom Error Response in CloudFront similar to the `error.html` page. But with it being 200 not exactly sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

There are few things happening there.

1. You need to map it to new origin if you want to point the **path to an S3 object**.
2. Your pattern is not having priority in CloudFront.

If you fix one of the above or both, then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> I have my S3 bucket setup for Static Website Hosting and is pubic

...but you selected the bucket from the dropdown list when defining the origin... yes?

You need to configure the origin domain name to use the web site hosting endpoint for the bucket.

> When you configure your CloudFront distribution, for the origin, enter the Amazon S3 static website hosting endpoint for your bucket. This value appears in the Amazon S3 console, on the Properties page under Static Website Hosting. For example: `http://bucket-name.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_S3Origin_website

If you don't do this, and you created folders in the bucket using the S3 console, then what you are currently observing is the expected behavior, a side effect of the way the console creates those imaginary folders.